# Codeigniter - Fatal error

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I have this error, `Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Input::file() in D:\xampp\htdocs\application\controllers\page.php on line 219` and use from [Multiple Uploads with JQuery and Code Igniter](http://www.mitesdesign.com/blog/open-source/multi-upload-jquery-code-igniter)  and [Extended Input for Files](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Extended_Input_for_Files)

This is my code:

```
if($this->input->file('userfile')){ //This is line 219
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png'; 
    $config['max_size']    = '1000'; 
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->load->library('Multi_upload');

    $files = $this->multi_upload->go_upload();
    //var_dump($files);
    if ( ! $files )
    {
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();                           
        echo $error;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $data3 = array();
        foreach ($files as $idx => $name) {
            //var_dump($name['name']);
            $data3[] = array(
                'relation' => $id_residence,
                'images' => $name['name'],
            );
        };
        $data333 = $this->db->insert_batch('hotel_image', $data3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which of these lines is the "line 219"?

Comment: a silly question: have you loaded `form` library already?

`$this->load->helper('form');`

Comment: @Ghazanfar - yes i loaded `url`.

Comment: its `form`, I updated my question, sorry.

Comment: @Ghazanfar - yes, `$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url')` in config/autoload.php

Comment: Have you checked that the prefix of the "Extended Input for Files" is ok? You should modify SM_ for MY_ or whatever is your prefix (set in config.php). I think the problem is with this extension, and it's not extending correctly to the CI_Input class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `isset()`

**try:**

```
$myInput = $this->input->file('userfile');
if(!empty($myInput)){
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just checked it, you may have a look at CodeIgniter File Upload: [link] (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) [link]